# Give a $2\times2$ real matrix, without zero elements satisfying following equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A $2\times2$ real matrix without zero elements named $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ that satisfies following equations:

- $A^2 = -I$
- $B^2 = 0$
- $CD = -DC$ with  $CD\neq0$

  I couldn't come up with any thing, Can you?

Comment: those two first constraints should lead you to something interesting. Can you satisfy those firstly?

Comment: How long did you try before deciding you couldn't find an example? Sometimes it takes a while to see what is going on.

Comment: @ShawnMehan Can you name them? 2x2 real matrix? :-)

Comment: @UmbertoP. About an hour, I suspect that it isn't possible and more than that that I wanted to share the results if I found them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\m}[1]{\begin{bmatrix} #1\end{bmatrix}}$

For all three questions one can give a "conceptual" solution, that is a solution with an explanation of why it should work, as opposed to just solving a bunch of equations, except for the "non-zero entries" part. In each case it seems incredibly likely that the solution can be modified to one with non-zero entries by conjugating with a generic invertible matrix.

For $A^2=-I$: In the plane, multiplying a vector by $-1$ is the same as rotating it through an angle $\pi$, which in turn is the same as rotating through an angle $\pi/2$ twice. So: Let $A_\theta=\m{\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)}$. Then $A_{\pi/2}^2=A_\pi=-I$, but $A_{\pi/2}$ has zero entries. Let $A=PA_{\pi/2}P^{-1}$ for a "random" invertible matrix $P$; if that doesn't work try a different $P$.

(Note I don't think that saying "keep trying til you find a $P$ that works" really negates my claim to be avoiding random diddling around here, *because*, not that I've proved it, it seems clear that "almost every" $P$ in any of various senses should work.)

FOr $B^2=0$: Both eigenvalues of $B$ must be $0$. The obvious example of a non-zero matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda=0,0$ is $\m{0&1\\0&0}$. This time I actually verified that if  $B=P\m{0&1\\0&0}P^{-1}$ where $P=\m{1&1\\1&2}$ then indeed $B$ has no zero entries.

For $CD=-DC\ne0$: Hmm. If $C$ happens to be invertible this says that $-D$ is similar to $D$, hence $D$ and $-D$ have the same eigenvalues. So the obvious candidate is $D=\m{1&0\\0&-1}$.

Now you think about this, and you realize that for that particular $D$ you can obtain $-D$ from $D$ by swapping the rows and then swapping the columns. Or to put the same thing in terms of concepts instead of calculations: If $D$ is the mmatrix for a linear transfomation with respect to the ordered basis $(b_1,b_2)$, then $-D$ is the matrix for the same transformation with respect to the basis $(b_2,b_1)$; so the "similarizer" should be the map $x\to(x_2,x_1)$. Sure enough, if $C=\m{0&1\\1&0}$ then $CD=-DC\ne0$. So if $P$ is a generic invertible matrix then $D'=PDP^{-1}$, $C'=PCP^{-1}$ should work.

Comment: $A_{\pi}$ has zero elements but the question asked about matrices with out zero elements.

Comment: Yes, $A_\pi$ has zero elements. But that's irrelevant; the point is that $A_\pi=-I$, so $A^2=-I$ if $A=A_{\pi/2}$. But as I realized a moment ago, $A_{\pi/2}$ also has zero elements. (Note however that any matrix _similar to_ $A_{\pi/2}$ also works...)

Comment: @FazeL Added solutions (almost) for the other two problems - Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\implies A^2=\begin{pmatrix}a^2+bc&b(a+d)\\c(a+d)&d^2+bc\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$ Notice that $$a^2+bc=d^2+bc\implies a^2=d^2$$ and you should now hopefully be able to do the rest.

Comment: I've already noticed that fact but couldn't used it to reach a conclusion.

Comment: Hint: Consider each case that $a=d$ and $a=-d$. We know that $b(a+d)=c(a+d)$, so...

Comment: Are you sure you've taken into account that matrices must be real and not complex?

Comment: As given in the question, "a $2\times2$ **real** matrix"